# Safe static_cast in C++ in a codebase

Tags: c++

How would you review this way of implementing a std::static_cast

```
template <typename ToType, typename FromType>
ToType safe_static_cast( const FromType &from )
{
    assert( from <= std::numeric_limits<ToType>::max() );
    assert( from >= std::numeric_limits<ToType>::min() );

    return static_cast<ToType>(from);
}
```

Is assertions on the limits a good way?

Comment: The `assert()` don't do anything in production. So there is no actual checking here. So all you are doing is removing a compiler warning. Sure if that's what you want but best option is to make sure you are suing the correct types.

Comment: While this is a very interesting question, it might be considered off-topic because it is hypothetical in nature, or a little to general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very interesting question.

First, I would reconsider the name. `safe_static_cast` implies that it is more general than it is. The types must have `std::numeric_limits` specializations in your implementation, so clearly you are thinking of numeric types. Maybe `safe_numeric_cast` or even `numeric_cast` would be a better name.

Secondly, `assert` is too often compiled out, so I would ask to consider alternatives which aren't. One alternative is throwing `std::out_of_range`. Another alternative is to saturate the destination type: if the source value is larger than the largest destination value, return the largest destination value.

Consider `FromType` = `int`, `from` = `-1`, `ToType` = `unsigned int`. Note that `-1 >= 0u` is `true`.

Consider the range of floating point types: `min()` is the lowest **positive** floating point value.

Consider floating point infinities: `numeric_cast<double, double>` should always be fine, right? But the comparison will fail for infinity.

Consider floating point nans: similarly, all comparisons fail for nans.